# Does jest.isolateModules allow for awaits inside of it?

Tags: jestjs

Am I able to await on my async test util methods inside of a `jest.isolateModules()` block?

The usage of `await` alongside `jest.isolateModules` is mentioned [here](https://dev.to/thetogi/jest-testing-mocking-modules-and-handling-module-state-using-typescript-and-es6-3jk4) but I'm unsure if this is correct or not.

I know `jest.isolateModulesAsync` exists, but that's not what I'm asking.